# Optimzing jsonfield filtering values of a certain index

Tags: django, django-orm

Scenario:

```
qs = mymodal.objects.values('foo__0__json_key').filter(foo__0__json_key__gte=numeric_value)
```

Where we know that "json_key" is a numeric value inside the 0th index of foo.

E.g.

```
foo = [{"json_key": 12}, {"json_key": 23} {...} ... xN ]
```

So my goal is to filter for each instance that has a the first jsonfield entry (In this case = 12) >= the provided numeric value, but it seems like my query approach has a very poor performance for running this query on e.g. 10 000 instances with foo being a field with more than 1000 entries.

What are your suggestions to imrpove my query? Indexing? I really need to make things faster.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually if data is structured, it makes not much sense to store that as a JSON blob in a *relational* database, because it makes querying less expressive and less efficient as well.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if data is structured, it makes not much sense to store that as a JSON blob in a *relational* database, because it makes querying less expressive and less efficient as well.

If these are PostgreSQL databases, you can try to add an index for this with:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db.models import F


class mymodal(models.Model):
    foo = JSONField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(F('foo__0__json_key'), name='json_key_index'),
        ]
```

This will then create a B-tree for the values, and likely make filtering more efficient.

But regardless, JSON blobs are not really a good concept in relational databases when querying, aggregating, etc. "inside" JSON blob objects, and they violate first normal form.

Comment: Hi, thanks, the implementation of our jsonfields is kind off old and would be unwise to change at this state. What if I'd like to index 'foo__0' is that possible?

Comment: Could I use a B-Tree index? Got that suggestion from somebody else, would that be the best solution for now?